# ReactJS nav items, not wrapping in toolbar component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm starting to make a navigation bar in my react project (so far without routing), and I'm having trouble making my NavigationItems to wrap to the navbar, right now they are aligned vertically.

I made my structure so that, I have a component called NavigationItem, which holds the properties for each item in the navbar.

```
import React from 'react';

import './NavigationItem.css'

const navigationItem = (props) =>(
        <li className="NavigationItem">
            <a 
            className={props.active ? "active" : null}
            href={props.link}> 
            {props.children} 
            </a>
        </li>
);

export default navigationItem;
```

I added some CSS, for styling, and to make it align with my toolbar component, which is the entire header for each view on my page.

```
    .NavigationItem{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.NavigationItem a {
    color: rgb(207, 182, 182);
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px 10px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

.NavigationItem a:hover, 
.NavigationItem a:active,
.NavigationItem a.active{
    background-color: rgb(126, 49, 49);
    border-bottom: 4px solid lightblue;
    
}
```

Here is the CSS I added, which should make it wrap, and I added an active class, so the user, can see the current page, they are on.

I then wrap all my items, inside a NavigationItems component:

```
   const navigationItems = () =>{
    return(
        <ul className="NavigationItems">
           <nav>
           <NavigationItem link="/" active>Burger Builder</NavigationItem>
           <NavigationItem link="/" >Checkout</NavigationItem>
           </nav>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Here I added some CSS aswell:

```
.NavigationItems{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}
```

Yet my items, don't align properly as they are aligned vertically, I attached a picture, to see how it looks, every active class works fine with the components, I just can't get the elements to wrap.

[image: here is the outlook I'm currently getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your nav tag from inside of your ul element. Now your'e creating a nav inside the ul before you create the li elements. Your li elements should be direct children to ul.

So something like this structure instead:

```
<nav>
<ul class="NavigationItems">
    <li class="NavigationItem">
        <a class="active" href="{props.link}">Burger Builder</a>
    </li>
    <li class="NavigationItem">
        <a href="{props.link}">Checkout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you